# Struts 2 select tag with values of a array list

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, valuestack

I am developing a simple struts application. In my JSP I have a dropdown list box (using `s:select` tag). I need to fill the values with a arraylist values in the action class. How can I do that? what changes needed in the `structs.xml` file for complete this?

**JSP:**

```
<s:select name="department" label="" list="departmentlist"  headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Department">
```

**Action class:**

```
private List<String> departmentlist = new ArrayList<String>();

public String xyz()
{
    departmentlist.add("aaa");
    departmentlist.add("bbb");
    departmentlist.add("ccc");
    departmentlist.add("ddd");
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: About what `structs.xml` are you talking?

Comment: after i googling, i found that add action mapping entries in struts configuration file for this. Anyway how can i show this arraylist values in drop down box ?

Comment: Create a getter for the list, then it will auto-populated.

Comment: already i tried that. i got the following error message.
"The requested list key 'departmentlist' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location] "

Comment: show your struts tag for success of this

Answer (score 2):

The error

> "The requested list key 'departmentlist' could not be resolved as a
> collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or
> people.{name} - [unknown location] "

means that the `<s:select>` tag is not able to resolve `departmentlist` as a collection. It is an OGNL expression which is trying to find the `departmentlist` in the value stack and if it not found or contains a `null` reference the `<s:select>` tag will complain. When you render the [`<s:select>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) make sure the list is in the value stack and is initialized

Answer (score 0):

Try to add get and set method for our field departmentlist,in your class
Exple : 
in your class controller put this method for your field departmentlist :

```
public  List<String> getDepartmentlist(){
  return this.departmentlist();
}

public void setDepartmentlist(List<String> departmentlist){
  return this.departmentlist = departmentlist;
}
```