# Variable cannot be resolved error in struts2

Tags: struts2

My requirement is am trying to populate pid(projectid) from project table and name from userdetails table as an drop down for a form.Am new to struts framework. Could someone please throw us some light on this issue please.

Here is the code:

**sprintform.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){$('.dateTxt').datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
            }); }); 
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: green">Sprint</h1>
    <s:form action="sprintInsert" namespace="/" method="post"
        name="sprintForm" theme="xhtml">
        <s:textfield name="title:" size="40" maxlength="40" required="true"
            label="Title" />
        <p>
            Begin Date: <input id="one" class="dateTxt" type="text"
                name="begindate" />
        </p>
        <p>
            End Date: <input id="two" class="dateTxt" type="text" name="enddate" />
        </p>
        <s:select label="ProjectId" headerKey="-1"
            headerValue="Select Project Id" list="projectidList" name="pid" />
<%--        <s:select label="Owner" headerKey="-1"
            headerValue="Select Sprint Owner" list="sprintownerList"
            name="sprintowner" /> --%>
        <tr>
            <td>State:</td>
            <td><select name="state">
                    <option value="">Choose a state..</option>
                    <option value="A">Active</option>
                    <option value="F">Future</option>
                    <option value="C">Close</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <s:textfield name="targetestimatedpoints" size="40" maxlength="40"
            required="true" label="Target Estimate pts:" />
        <s:textfield name="totalestimatedpoints" size="40" maxlength="40"
            required="true" label="Total Estimate pts:" />
        <s:textfield name="totaldefaultestimatedhours" size="40"
            maxlength="40" required="true" label="Total Detail Estimate Hrs: " />
        <s:textfield name="todohours:" size="40" maxlength="40"
            required="true" label="Total To Do Hrs:" />
        <s:textfield name="description: :" size="40" maxlength="40"
            required="true" label="Description: " />
        <tr align="right">
            <td><div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="save">
                </div>
            <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </s:form>
    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
        <div id="fieldErrors">
            <s:actionerror />
        </div>
    </s:if>
</body>
</html>
```

**SprintAction.java**:

```
package com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.bits.sprintanalyzer.ResourceException;
import com.bits.sprintanalyzer.dao.SprintDAO;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SprintAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SprintAction.class);
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6257623073537028210L;

    private String title;
    private String begindate;
    private String enddate;
    private String pid;
    private String sprintowner;
    private String state;
    private int targetestimatedpoints;
    private int totalestimatedpoints;
    private int totaldefaultestimatedhours;
    private int todohours;
    private String description;

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }


    public String getSprintowner() {
        return sprintowner;
    }

    public void setSprintowner(String sprintowner) {
        this.sprintowner = sprintowner;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getTargetestimatedpoints() {
        return targetestimatedpoints;
    }

    public void setTargetestimatedpoints(int targetestimatedpoints) {
        this.targetestimatedpoints = targetestimatedpoints;
    }

    public int getTotalestimatedpoints() {
        return totalestimatedpoints;
    }

    public void setTotalestimatedpoints(int totalestimatedpoints) {
        this.totalestimatedpoints = totalestimatedpoints;
    }

    public int getTotaldefaultestimatedhours() {
        return totaldefaultestimatedhours;
    }

    public void setTotaldefaultestimatedhours(int totaldefaultestimatedhours) {
        this.totaldefaultestimatedhours = totaldefaultestimatedhours;
    }

    public int getTodohours() {
        return todohours;
    }

    public void setTodohours(int todohours) {
        this.todohours = todohours;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String display() throws Exception {
        return INPUT;
    }

    public String getBegindate() {
        return begindate;
    }

    public void setBegindate(String begindate) {
        this.begindate = begindate;
    }

    public String getEnddate() {
        return enddate;
    }

    public void setEnddate(String enddate) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<String> getpidList() throws ResourceException {
        return SprintDAO.getpidList();
    }

    public List<String> getOwnerList() throws ResourceException {
        return SprintDAO.getOwnerList();
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {

    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("title" + title);
        LOG.info("begindate" + begindate);
        LOG.info("enddate" + enddate);
        LOG.info("pid" + pid);
        LOG.info("sprintowner" + sprintowner);
        LOG.info("state" + state);
        LOG.info("targetestimatedpoints" + targetestimatedpoints);
        LOG.info("totalestimatedpoints" + totalestimatedpoints);
        LOG.info("totaldefaultestimatedhours" + totaldefaultestimatedhours);
        LOG.info("todohours" + todohours);
        LOG.info("description" + description);
        // ProjectDAO.insert(projectname,description,scrummaster,productowner,begindate,enddate);
        int i = SprintDAO.save(this);
        if (i > 0) {
            return "success";
        }
        return "error";
    }

}
```

**SprintDAO**:

```
package com.bits.sprintanalyzer.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.bits.sprintanalyzer.ResourceException;
import com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.SprintAction;
import com.bits.sprintanalyzer.util.ConnectionUtil;

public class SprintDAO {
    private static final String PROJECTQUERY = "select pid from project";
    private static final String USERQUERY = "select name from userdetail";

    public static List<String> getpidList() throws ResourceException{
        List<String> projectidList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // this should be populated from DB

        try (Connection con = ConnectionUtil.INSTANCE.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(PROJECTQUERY)){
                ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    projectidList.add(rs.getString(1));
                }
        return projectidList;
}
        catch (SQLException | ResourceException e) {
            throw new ResourceException("Failed to validate project id", e);
        }
}
    public static List<String> getOwnerList() throws ResourceException{
        List<String> sprintownerList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // this should be populated from DB

        try (Connection con = ConnectionUtil.INSTANCE.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(USERQUERY)){
                ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    sprintownerList.add(rs.getString(1));
                }
        return sprintownerList;
}
        catch (SQLException | ResourceException e) {
            throw new ResourceException("Failed to validate productowner", e);
        }
}

    //insert into database
        public static int save(SprintAction SA) throws Exception{ 
            int status=0;
            try{
            Connection con = ConnectionUtil.INSTANCE.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into sprint(pid,title,begindate,enddate,owner,state,targetestimatedpoints,totalestimatedpoints,totaldefaultestimatedhours,todohours,description) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, SA.getPid());
            ps.setString(2, SA.getTitle());
            ps.setString(3, SA.getBegindate());
            ps.setString(4, SA.getEnddate());
            ps.setString(5, SA.getSprintowner());
            ps.setString(6, SA.getState());
            ps.setInt(7, SA.getTargetestimatedpoints()); 
            ps.setInt(8, SA.getTotalestimatedpoints());
            ps.setInt(9, SA.getTotaldefaultestimatedhours());
            ps.setInt(10, SA.getTodohours());
            ps.setString(11, SA.getDescription());
            status=ps.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();}  
        return status;  
        }  


}
```

**struts.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1.7//EN"
    "/WEB-INF/classes/struts-2.1.7.dtd">

<struts>
    <!--
    You could also set the constants in the struts.properties file
    placed in the same directory as struts.xml
    -->
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="sprintanalyzer" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <!--
        If no class attribute is specified the framework will assume success and
        render the result index.jsp
        If no name value for the result node is specified the success value is the default
        -->
        <action name="">
            <result>/jsp/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <!--
        If the URL is hello.action then call the execute method of class HelloWorldAction.
        If the result returned by the execute method is success render the HelloWorld.jsp
        -->
        <action name="login" class="com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.LoginAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/jsp/sprintanalyzer.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/jsp/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="projectform" class="com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.ProjectAction"
            method="display">
            <result name="input">/jsp/projectform.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="projectInsert" class="com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.ProjectAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/jsp/sprintanalyzer.jsp</result>
        </action>   
            <action name="sprintform" class="com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.SprintAction"
            method="display">
            <result name="input">/jsp/sprintform.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="sprintInsert" class="com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.SprintAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/jsp/sprintanalyzer.jsp</result>
        </action>   

    </package>

</struts>
```

Issue is coming from both `projectidlist` and `sprintownerList`. Please advise accordingly.

Please find below stacktrace:

```
2016-10-01T18:23:38.916+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:38,916 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The first TextProvider in the ValueStack (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport) could not locate the message resource with key 'Login'
2016-10-01T18:23:38.917+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:38,917 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The default value expression 'Login' was evaluated and did not match a property.  The literal value 'Login' will be used.
2016-10-01T18:23:38.925+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:38,924 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The first TextProvider in the ValueStack (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport) could not locate the message resource with key 'Login'
2016-10-01T18:23:38.925+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:38,925 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The default value expression 'Login' was evaluated and did not match a property.  The literal value 'Login' will be used.
2016-10-01T18:23:57.121+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:57,120 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The first TextProvider in the ValueStack (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport) could not locate the message resource with key 'Login'
2016-10-01T18:23:57.121+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:57,121 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The default value expression 'Login' was evaluated and did not match a property.  The literal value 'Login' will be used.
2016-10-01T18:23:57.128+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:57,128 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The first TextProvider in the ValueStack (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport) could not locate the message resource with key 'Login'
2016-10-01T18:23:57.129+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:23:57,128 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The default value expression 'Login' was evaluated and did not match a property.  The literal value 'Login' will be used.
2016-10-01T18:24:03.841+0530|Severe: Sat Oct 01 18:24:03 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2016-10-01T18:24:04.022+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:24:04,021 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The first TextProvider in the ValueStack (com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.LoginAction) could not locate the message resource with key 'welcome to Sprint Analyzer Tool'
2016-10-01T18:24:04.022+0530|Info: 2016-10-01 18:24:04,022 WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper.warn:45 - The default value expression 'welcome to Sprint Analyzer Tool' was evaluated and did not match a property.  The literal value 'welcome to Sprint Analyzer Tool' will be used.
2016-10-01T18:24:06.835+0530|Warning: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'pid': The requested list key 'projectidList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:358)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.sprintform_jsp._jspx_meth_s_select_0(sprintform_jsp.java:236)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.sprintform_jsp._jspx_meth_s_form_0(sprintform_jsp.java:144)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.sprintform_jsp._jspService(sprintform_jsp.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptorcom.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-10-01T18:24:06.844+0530|Warning: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'pid': The requested list key 'projectidList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:358)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)

    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at
```

Here is the login code:

```
package com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.bits.sprintanalyzer.ResourceException;
import com.bits.sprintanalyzer.dao.LoginDAO;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoginAction.class);
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6877145894906143530L;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    @Override
    public void validate(){
        if (username==null || username.length()==0 || password ==null || password.length() ==0 )
            addActionError(getText("User name or Password cannot be null"));
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try{
            if( LoginDAO.isValidUser(username, password) ){
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            else
            {
                addActionError(getText("Invalid Username or Password"));
            }
        }catch(ResourceException e){
            LOG.error("Failed to valid User", e);
            addActionError(getText("Something Went wrong with DBConnection"));
        }
        return INPUT;
    }

}
```

Latest stacktrace after changing connection string:

```
2016-10-01T18:55:04.396+0530|Warning: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'pid': The requested list key 'projectidList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:358)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at va:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

Comment: Please add the exception stack that you are getting. variable cannot be resolved is not sufficient, need to check which variable.

Comment: Hi Rohit,Here is the stack trace.

Comment: Pasted stacktrace in original post Rohit.

Comment: your action class is com.bits.sprintanalyzer.action.LoginAction, don't know whats going on in it, please add that too. Also add your MySQL db connection string.

Comment: Added LoginAction code.

Comment: Hi Rohit if you need any other details will share that too..

Comment: You need to sort out the db connection exception first, check the answer. also add your connection string so as to sort it out. Once, it is sorted out you have to update the exception stack in question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [struts select tag with values of a array list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760673/struts-select-tag-with-values-of-a-array-list)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You have MySQL connection exception as below:

```
Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.  
According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set.
```

To resolve this use the connection string like below:(change the db name to your existing db name)

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

This needs to be sorted first, that's why the values of the variables are not been rendered

**2)** In the Latest trace the requested list key '**projectidList**' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type.

This error occurs when you try to access a list/collection which haven't been created.

Try to  initialize the collection objects `List<String> projectidList` at class level.

when particular action is triggered at that time, JSP page is not knowing the the type of field, in this case, when you write `List<String> projectidList = new ArrayList<String>();` instead of this, change it to `ArrayList projectidList = new ArrayList();`.

**Make sure that you access list after the action class is instantiated i.e. corresponding action is called.
If you want to directly access it before calling action make it static and access it inside jsp.**

Comment: I added that Rohit but still failing with same error.

Comment: are you using netbeans? NetBeans's default is to use SSL. try with this "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false"

Comment: Am using eclipse IDE , would like to share my screen once and ask you actually approach i did worked for 1 screen but not working for this screen.

Comment: am using  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/scrumdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";